# Doma-Genで自動生成されたEntityの各フィールドJavadocコメントをセットするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Tags: java, orm

Doma-Gen 1.35 で SQLServer2012に接続し
Dao・Entityクラスの自動生成を試しているのですが、EntityクラスのフィールドJavadocコメントが空っぽ状態となり困っています。
Doma-GenでSQLServerのテーブル自動生成する場合、コメントは生成できないのでしょうか？？

doma-gen-build.xmlのEntityConfigはデフォルト(showDbComment=true)のままです。

コメントは下記の手順で設定しています。

> [オブジェクトエクスプローラー] →　対象のテーブルを選択して[右クリック] → [デザイナ] → 対象のカラムを選択 → [列のプロパティ]の下のほうにある[説明]の項目に付けたい説明を入力

※関係ないかもしれませんが・・・
[カラムの説明取得SQL](https://qiita.com/t_takahari/items/0f828bde9c830d316779)の取得方法を利用すると説明は取得できるのですが
内部で発行しているっぽいT-SQL(sp_columns_100)では取得できないことまで確認はしました・・・。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原因はSQLServerのJDBC Driverが対応していないからだと思います。

Doma-Genは[DatabaseMetaData#getColumns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))のREMARKS列を使ってJavadocコメントを生成していますが、[SQLServerのJDBC DriverのドキュメントでDatabaseMetaData#getColumns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/getcolumns-method-sqlserverdatabasemetadata)のREMARKS列を確認すると以下のような注意書きが見られます。

> SQL Server always returns null for this column

SQLServer固有の方法で取得できるのであれば、Doma-GenをカスタマイズすることでJavadocコメントをセットすることができると思います。

Comment: やはりそのままでは対応ができないのですね。doma-genのカスタマイズは恥ずかしながら頭になかったので、試してみます！ありがとうございます。

Comment: カスタマイズ方法があっているのか自身はありませんが・・・MssqlGenDialectのisJdbcCommentUnavailableとgetColumnCommentMapをオーバライドすることで期待していた動きになってくれました！回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: はい、そのカスタマイズ方法で合っています！うまくいったようでよかったです。